# How to transform a series attributeNames to headers with corresponding attributeValues

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Situation

I have a dataframe `attributes` that holds some attribute information about cars in 3 series:

```
attributes = {'brand': ['Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Audi A4'],
          'attributeName': ['wheels','doors','fuelType','wheels','color','wheels'],
          'attributeValue': ['4','2','hybrid','4','red','4']
        }
```

### Expected result

```
result = {'brand':   ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Audi A4'],
          'wheels':  ['4','4','4'],
          'doors':   ['2','',''],
          'fuelType':['hybrid','',''],
          'color':   ['','red','']
         }
```

### How can I realize this?

Transform the values from `attributeName` into series to represent its `attributeValue` for each brand/car in one row.

With `get_dummies` I get this transformation, but only with true/false values not with the original values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `pivot`:

```
attributes.pivot(index='brand',
                 columns='attributeName',
                 values='attributeValue').fillna('')
```

or, shorter as your columns are in right order:

```
attributes.pivot(*attributes).fillna('')
```

To format it exactly as your provided output (except column order, please give details on that), you can use:

```
(attributes.pivot(index='brand', columns='attributeName', values='attributeValue')
           .fillna('').rename_axis(None, axis=1)
           .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
            brand color doors fuelType wheels
0         Audi A4                           4
1     Honda Civic           2   hybrid      4
2  Toyota Corolla   red                     4
```

Comment: Comunity wiki for dupes?

Comment: Why answering for dupes?

Comment: @jezrael  I haven't noticed your comments yet, but I found the answer and especially the `attributes.pivot(*attributes).fillna('')` part very helpful, I didn't know any better at the time either. I appreciate your super precise answers and not only yours. Sometimes you just don't realise that it's a duplicate, a question that's been asked a thousand times, because you're maybe fresh into a subject. so i still think it's good if time allows and you feel like leaving an answer. It can't hurt and sometimes you find real pearls. thanks to you and mozway

Comment: @HedgeHog - No problem, sometimes happens.